# ServiceStatck Redis Client Support for Sentinel?

Tags: redis, servicestack

Is ServiceStack working on any updates to the Redis Client objects to support Redis Sentinel?  Thanks

Comment: Please give more specific details what you really want to ask.

Comment: redis sentinel allows you to run redis in sentinel mode to monitor running instances of redis.  It will promote a new master when the master goes down.  You can not use this feature using the current servicestack redis client managers.  There needs to be some dev done so the redis client managers will connect to a list of redis sentinels to discover the current master/slaves.

Comment: Can you add this as a feature request to [ServiceStack's UserVoice](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) so we can track it, thx.